# Add property from string to dynamically created ListElement through ListModel.append()

Tags: qt, qml

What is the correct approach to insert dynamic properties to dynamically created ListElements in a ListModel using JS?
It's seems that i can't enter a variable reference between { } for supplying properties, it only works for values.`model` is a `LisModel` and this function should create the `ListElements` with both these properties.

```
function getReadings(model) {
    var timeStr = "hour_0";
    var temp = 11.9;

    model.append({day: 1, timestr: 11.9}); //Error
    model.append({day: 1, hour_0: 11.9});  //OK!

}
```

I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: Using the role names in the delegate seems difficult with what you are trying to do since they'll be changing. Some might be undefined for certain indexes.

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind you're working with javascript. The { } is a JSON object, which is the parameter for the append( ) method.

This worked for me:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors {top: parent.top; right: parent.right}
    width: 100
    height: 100

    onClicked:  {
        var myKey = "day"
        var myValue = "Saturday"
        var json = { };
        json[myKey] = myValue;
        listModel.append(json)
    }
}
```